# gnuplot surface plot set cutoff with pm3d

Tags: gnuplot

I'm getting this plot using `pm3d` `parula` color pallet and my z range is et at `[:.4]`

[image]
as you can see the cut at the z=.4 is not uniform surface cut, its like spiky. How do I make this uniform? 
Also another question, is there a option in gnuplot to skip row and column similar to python matplotlib's `rstride` and `cstride`

Comment: `set pm3d noborder;  splot FOO with pm3d` should remove the purple lines (not sure if that is what you mean by "spiky").  As to the blue-green surface, if the sharp peaks at the rear are artifacts I would guess they are due to incorrect values at the bounding condition on y.  Are you plotting from data or from a function?

Comment: let me clarify, the data has three global peak, in middle of those three 'U' shaped dip, you can see the dip in the middle, but the two side peaks go beyond .4, and theres no abrupt spike there. If I put z range [:.4] then, instead of a uniform cut at .4, I get a spiky cut of surface, which I don't want.

Comment: So the left and right features should be truncated cones?  I think that would be possible.  Please show the actual splot command you are using. Possibly it can be modified to cap the z value at zmax rather than relying on clipping at a later stage to remove surface quadrangles with one or more corners out of range.

Comment: Yes those would be truncated cones, I'm just using a simple `sp 'filename' w l ` command, nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

```
  set pm3d noborder
  set zrange [*:0.4]
  splot 'filename' using 1:2:( $3<0.4 ? $3 : 0.4 ) with pm3d
```

This should produce truncated cones.  The clipped region is rendered as a solid (flat) surface with the color of palette value 0.4.
If you require that the truncated region appears as a void rather than as flat surface, the following command sequence may work. This is a little-used pm3d option and I am not certain of the requirements on the structure of the data.

```
set pm3d noborder
set pm3d clip1in
set zrange  [*:0.4]
set cbrange [*:1.0]
splot 'filename' using 1:2:( $3<0.4 ? $3 : 0.41 ) with pm3d
```

[image]